# Problem in Cakephp + WAMP Installation

Tags: php, cakephp, wamp

I am new to cakePHP And I am having a problem getting it working while using WAMP.

I have already copied cakephp folders/files into WAMP's www folder and DocumetRoot "C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\webroot"

Is there more I need to do? I am getting a page when clicking on localhost from WAMP but it is showing many errors including:

> Fatal error: Class 'Debugger' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\view\pages\home.ctp
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in  C:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\libs\inflector.php

Comment: Which version of CakePHP and PHP do you use?
For the database connection you must setup the file `app\config\database.php` from `database.php.default`

Comment: i have latest version of cake php and php.

Comment: the databas has configured but still same error.

Comment: Could you please show the full list of errors? There's probably one further up the list that will be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i think you downloaded the beta version of cake 2.0..

i have encountered that problem too..

you should use cakephp's stable versions...

cakephp  2.0 is now stable.....

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert apache `.htacces` file into root directory.